# Insert into Memory Optimized Table from non optimized

Tags: t-sql, cross-database, memory-optimized-tables

I have two database.
Primary have a DDL triggers so i can't create memory optimized tables there. So i created secondary database and create there table with memory optimized on. Now, in procedure on primary database i need insert copy data from other table to this optimized.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO InMemory.dbo.DestTable_InMem SELECT * FROM @T;
```

And i have:

```
A user transaction that accesses memory optimized tables or natively compiled modules cannot access more than one user database or databases model and msdb, and it cannot write to master.
```

Did exists some workarounds from it?

I cannot move my procedure to second database.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way than using a native procedure to INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE in an in-memory table.

See: [A Guide to Query Processing for Memory-Optimized Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/a-guide-to-query-processing-for-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

To move from one DB to the other, the source table must exists locally